# Python Can't understand conditional statement in loop

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements, statements

Need help in python. This code is from [leetcode.com](http://leetcode.com), one of the solutions for this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/description/) and cannot understand conditional statement there, exactly the code "`stack[-1][1]`"

```
class Solution(object):

def dailyTemperatures(self, temps):

    if not temps:
        return []

    result = [0] * len(temps)
    stack = []

    for curr_idx, curr_temp in enumerate(temps):

        while stack and curr_temp > stack[-1][1]: # not clear, and I know, it is not a type of access to list element

            last_idx, last_temp = stack.pop()
            result[last_idx] = curr_idx - last_idx

        stack.append((curr_idx, curr_temp))

    return result
```

Comment: Yes it is. `stack` is a list, `stack[-1]`, its last element, is a tuple, and `stack[-1][1]` is the element of this tuple at index 1.

Comment: Please check any tutorial that includes non-trivial lists, such as a list of lists.  This *is* perfectly legal access to a deeper structure.  Think of it as `x = stack[-1]; y = x[1]`, if that helps.

Comment: Thank you guys! Now it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning the second element of whatever is in the last index of stack

for instance, if the stack was a list of strings like

```
stack = ['abc','def','ghi']
```

than stack[-1][1] returns

```
stack[-1] <-- 'ghi'
stack[-1][1] <-- 'h'
```